# How do I change the root path in nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I have installed `nginx` on my **Ubunut 12.04**, I am not able to change the root directory for the nginx,

This is the default `nginx` configuration file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        root /var/www
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

I tried changing root to `/var/www/` but some how it doesn't want to change.
I tried restarting the `nginx` but I am not able to change the root directory.

Comment: Use command `nginx -t` to check for syntax errors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your configuration is missing the `;` at the end of `root` directive.

Try this:

```
root /var/www;
```

Comment: Wow.. you got me there, that works.. thanks for the quick reply :) getting rid of Apache was hurting me.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `/etc/nginx/sites-available`.

```sh
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
```

2. Open `default`.

```sh
sudo nano default
```

You will get something like this, opened on your nano editor: 
(I have removed the comments for the simplicity of this answer)

```sh
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
   
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

3. Edit the line `root /var/www/html;` to `root /your/specified/path;`
4. Save the file & exit.
5. Restart nginx

```sh
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Now, you should be good to go.

Check the server status and see if its is active (without throwing any error):

```sh
sudo systemctl status nginx
```